# Xcode 14.3: Build and Archive error when copying private framework during build - framework: no such file or directory

Tags: xcodebuild, ipa, ipados, xcode14.3, xcode-archive

Ever since I've upgrade to Xcode 14.3, our project has been failing to archive after build, with following error:

```
Copy /<redacted_path_to_project>/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/LiquidDecisions/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Decisions.app/Frameworks/LiquidPlatformKit.framework /<redacted_path_to_project_root>/Frameworks/LiquidPlatformKit.framework (in target '<AppName' from project '<AppName>')

error: /<redacted_path_to_project_root>/Frameworks/../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/LiquidPlatformKit.framework: No such file or directory (in target '<AppName>' from project '<AppName>')
```

`LiquidPlatformKit.framework` is our private library/framework for our iPadOS project.
I'm not sure why is this popping for Xcode 14.3+; and its the same error we're seeing in Xcode 15 beta as well.

I've seen some similar issue but for CocoaPods and since our framework is not part of Pods that solution is not applicable to us.

Have you faced similar issue? any suggestions to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.